# Cannot GET /api/admin/get-all-doctors I have created a doctors end point and trying fetch that API and getting the error

Tags: javascript, routes

This is adminroute using post method I created two end points get-all-doctors and get-all-users but I am unable to fetch either of them. Cannot `GET /api/admin/get-all-users.xhr.js:251`.

> GET http://localhost:3000/api/admin/get-all-users 404 (Not Found).

I had checked multiple time but did not find the error.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/userModel");
const Doctor = require("../models/doctorModel");
const authMiddleware=require('../middlewares/authMiddleware');

router.post("/get-all-doctors", authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const doctors = await Doctor.find({});
    res
      .status(200)
      .send({
        message: "Doctors fetched successfully",
        success: true,
        data: doctors,
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send({
      message: "error applying doctor account",
      success: false,
      error,
    });
  }
});
router.post("/get-all-users", authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await User.find({});
    res
      .status(200)
      .send({
        message: "users fetched successfully",
        success: true,
        data: users,
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send({
      message: "error applying doctor account",
      success: false,
      error,
    });
  }
});
module.exports = router;
```

Trying fetching `userRoute` from this file:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Layout from "../../components/Layout";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { showLoading, hideLoading } from "../../redux/alertsSlice";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Table } from "antd";

function Userslist() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const dispatach = useDispatch();
  const getUsersData = async () => {
    try {
      dispatach(showLoading());
      const response = await axios.get("/api/admin/get-all-users", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
        },
      });
      dispatach(hideLoading());
      if (response.data.success) {
        setUsers(response.data.data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      dispatach(hideLoading());
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getUsersData();
  }, []);
  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Name",
      dataIndex: "name",
    },
    {
      title: "Email",
      dataIndex: "email",
    },
    {
      title: "Created At",
      dataIndex: "created at",
    },
    {
      title: "Actions",
      dataIndex: "actions",
      render: (text, record) => (
        <div className="d-fles">
          <h1 className="anchor">Block</h1>
        </div>
      ),
    },
  ];
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1 className="page-header">Users List</h1>
      <Table columns={columns} dataSource={users}/>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default Userslist;
```

This is server.js, neither am I able to fetch users API nor doctors.

[image]

not `userlist` unable to fetch `userRoute`

Comment: Depending on the environment, it looks like your server listening on port 5000, but the error message refers to port 3000.

Comment: check whether you mentioned doctors api router in /api route controller.
Also, you're calling it directly with axios. If you didn't configure it, you should call it with full path: http://localhost:3000/api/admin/get-all-users

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you're calling axios directly, so you may have to provide the base url for a request.

```
 const response = await axios.get("/api/admin/get-all-users",
```

Try to change it to this:

```
 const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/admin/get-all-users",
```

also, check your environment if you set up port. Also you're using sub-router which is responsible for `/api` pathpoint. So check if you mentioned your doctors api in this endpoint.